# setup AOSP source on local gerrit

Tags: gerrit

I would like to setup a local copy of android source into local **gerrit**.

I installed **gerrit** and used `git clone --mirror` to clone android under 
/home/gerrit2/review_site/git/ with `repo sync` , restarted gerrit and i can see all repositories as projects in Gerrit, but I cannot access them when I click on the project I get:

> Code Review - Error The page you requested was not found, or you do
>   not have permission to view this page

Then I found that I'm able to browse two repositories: `git-repo` and `kernel`

I looked at my `/home/gerrit2/review_site/git/` and I understand that everything that is in nested directories cannot be accessed:

```
.repo
device
git-repo.git
kernel.git
platform
vendor
```

So only `kernel.git` and `git-repo.git` can be accessed normally in gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

well i found the solution.
What i did not mention is that i am using http proxy with gerrit and i found the fix in the Apache httpd configuration, had to add "nocanon" option into following line:

ProxyPass /gerrit/ http://MY_GERRIT_IP:8081/gerrit/ nocanon